# modeling Game data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do some statistical analysis of game data in pandas.

My raw data is stored by game with a "home_team" and an "away_team" (in fact the raw data is stored in mongDb with a denormalized "teams" property that is a list of the two teams, which makes it easy to query by team for all their games)

I'm trying to decide how to index my data when I put it into a DataFrame.

If I put in a row for each team for each game, I will have two rows for each game, and it will be easy to find games by team, but it will have dupe rows if i try to aggregate across all games.

Basically i'm stuck trying to get the two different subsets (all games with Team A, and all games within a certain time period)

Do i just need to have two different DataFrame's for the different ways I need to slice my data?

Comment: why don't you post some sample frames your operations on them? you can have dups or a multi-level index (sounds like what you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your df:

```
                  Home_team Away_team  Home_score  Away_score
GameID Date                                                  
1      2013-01-23    Team A    Team B           5           1
2      2013-01-23    Team C    Team D           3           3
3      2013-01-30    Team A    Team C           1           2
4      2013-01-30    Team B    Team D           2           3
```

You can slice by date with something like:

```
start = pd.datetime(2013,1,20)
end = pd.datetime(2013,1,25)

selection = (df.index.get_level_values('Date') >= start) & (df.index.get_level_values('Date') <= end)

df[selection]

                  Home_team Away_team  Home_score  Away_score
GameID Date                                                  
1      2013-01-23    Team A    Team B           5           1
2      2013-01-23    Team C    Team D           3           3
```

And by team with:

```
team = ['Team C']

df[df.apply(lambda x: x.isin(team)).max(axis=1)]
```

or multiple teams:

```
team = ['Team A','Team C']

df[df.apply(lambda x: x.isin(team)).max(axis=1)]

                  Home_team Away_team  Home_score  Away_score
GameID Date                                                  
1      2013-01-23    Team A    Team B           5           1
2      2013-01-23    Team C    Team D           3           3
3      2013-01-30    Team A    Team C           1           2
```

You can rearrange the columns and indices a bit, but there is definitely no need to use two DF's for these kind of queries.